# Mysql queries hanging. Processlist shows query state is null

Tags: php, mysql

I'm using MySQL version: 5.1.73 Source distribution

I've been calling a certain query from PHP for weeks and never had a problem.  Suddenly yesterday the PHP page no longer loads.  When I try to debug, I see that the query is hanging in MySQL.

Here's what the processlist is showing:

```
+----+------+-----------+---------------+---------+------+-------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Id | User | Host      | db            | Command | Time | State | Info                                                                                                 |
+----+------+-----------+---------------+---------+------+-------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  8 | root | localhost | assy_dirs_vcb | Query   | 1396 | NULL  | SELECT       IF(vcb.date_in,date_format(vcb.date_in, '%m/%d/%Y'),''),
                                                vcb.type,
                                                IF(vcb.pilo |
| 11 | root | localhost | assy_dirs_vcb | Query   | 1364 | NULL  | SELECT       IF(vcb.date_in,date_format(vcb.date_in, '%m/%d/%Y'),''),
                                                vcb.type,
                                                IF(vcb.pilo |
| 23 | root | localhost | assy_dirs_vcb | Query   |    0 | NULL  | show processlist                                                                                     |
+----+------+-----------+---------------+---------+------+-------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

The table is small, when the query was working it would return in about a second.  I've tried restarting the mysqld service, but it had no effect.

I need to get this back up and running.  What could be the cause, or what needs to be restarted?